# How do I click on this element in TestComplete?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium

I need to click on a web element, within TestComplete, this element looks like this:

[image]

I outlined its boundary using heavy-black line.

The problem is, by default, an element is always clicked in its middle point, and for this element above, clicking its middle point produces no results as it does not click this plus sign.

Within TestComplete, this element can not be broken further down into smaller elements.

I can use Selenium in JavaScript to click it, but is there is an other way?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you record a keyword test in TestComplete, this action will be recorded as ClickButton. If you switch to "Click" instead of "ClickButton", you can specify an X/Y offset from the top left corner of the control.

To make this change, record the click in a KeywordTest, double-click the step, On-Screen Action form opens. Navigate to the Specify a Method or Property page, and change ClickButton to Click, click Next, then set the Operation Parameters to the desired X/Y offset. The default is -1, -1 which indicates the center of the control. The top left corner of the control would actually be 0,0.